# Rails 3 routes to wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I wanted to create a new action and I call it "showemployees". That's what I did already:

-> in the controller:

```
def showemployees
end
```

-> creating  app/views/employees/showemployees.html.erb

-> in config/routes

`match "/employees/showemployees"  => "employees#showemployees"`

I thought this is enough for opening the showemployees.html.erb now via *localhost:3000/employees/showemployees* , but it seems like Rails still routes through the show action (from resources :employees) and doesn't take the showemployees-action, because it tells me

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in EmployeesController#show
Couldn't find Employee with ID=showemployees
```

What do I need to change so Rails takes the showemployees-action?

---

the source code of my route:

```
System::Application.routes.draw do

  match "/employees/showemployees" => "employees#showemployees" #für showemployees.html.erb

  root :to => "employees#index"

  resources :course_to_dos

  resources :current_qualifications

  resources :expected_qualifications

  resources :skills

  resources :employees

  resources :positions

  resources :admin


end
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the `match` statement before the `resources` statement in your `routes.rb`? The order matters in some cases.

Comment: yes, I already put the `match` before every statement, because it's written in the comments of the routes file that the order is important, but it didn't work. :(

Comment: So, which route do you actually have? `match "/employees"` or `match "/employees/showemployees"`? Your example does not match what you say you have.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to rename the actions to *show_multiple*, *update_multiple* and use nested routes if you have any dependencies

Comment: This "smells" to me. What does the `showemployees` action do that the `index` action wouldn't? I agree with mikhailov

Comment: I have both, the `/employees` and the `/employees/showemployees`. Because I already modified the index page (`/employees`) so it has a different task than before. It contains a search bar for searching employees and with some link to the show action. But I still need some "admin-backend" for someone who wants to modify the employees (create new ones, edit employees, delete and so on...) so I created a new action `/employees/showemployees`. I know, maybe it's not the best solution, I think I should change the action so "showemployees" is the index and "index" is the "admin-page".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to walk by Rails-way, if you want to get collection, use the collection

```
resources :employees do
  collection do
    get :showemployees
  end
end
```

Comment: *match "/employees" => "employees#showemployees"* is not needed anymore

Comment: great! This is working smooth! and for this, I don't need the `match`- method anymore, am I right? 
And just for understanding, that what we used is like it's written in chapter 2.9.2 of rubyguide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?

Comment: named routes **match** useful for non-REST routes, if you need something special or catch non-defined routes (*). RESTful controllers is the good approach, try to keep it while design your architecture

Answer (score 3):

If you post your full routes file we can make a definitive call, but based on the error message, it looks like you have a broader route definition mapping to employees#show defined above this route in such a way that it is getting matched.

Routes are evaluated in the order they are defined, so if you have a very broad route pattern defined above a narrow one, your narrow route will never be called.

edit: you'll want to take the forward slash out of your route and add the showemployees to the actual URL, so that it reads

```
 match "employees/showemployees" => "employees#showemployees"
```

Comment: I've added my sourcecode for the routes-file in my post at the beginning. Is it helpful? Do you need anything else? 
Even I have the `match` statement at the beginning, it still doesn't want to take this action.

Comment: The routes file you've added shows `match "/employees" => "employees#showemployees"` rather than `match "/employees/showemployees" => "employees#showemployees"`. Correcting that should fix it for you.